# Create an expression in ACCESS 2010

Tags: sql, ms-access, if-statement

Thank you in advance!  I'm a novice, so plain and simple explanations would greatly be appreciated. I *really* don't know what I'm doing, but I have grand concepts w/o any idea how to execute them.

I am creating an append query in Access 2010 and I want to identify Col_C as yes, if the word "red" appears in Col_B and everything else as no.

Desired Result

```
#Col A   Col B   Col C 
1      red       y    
2      blue      n    
3      red       y    
4      green     n    
5      red blue   y
```

I don't know how to write the if then statement.

```
INSERT into TABLE1  
SELECT [TABLE2].[Col_A], [TABLE2].[CoL_B]  
IF [TABLE2].[Col_B] like "*red`*`" then add y to Col_C else n  
FROM [TABLE2]
```

I know it's a bad attempt, but I've been researching and the explanations aren't clear enough for me to proceed.

Answer (score 0):

It could be:

```
INSERT INTO 
    TABLE1  
    ([Col_A], [CoL_B], [Col_C])
SELECT 
    [TABLE2].[Col_A], 
    [TABLE2].[CoL_B],  
    IIF([TABLE2].[Col_B] = "red", "y", "n")
FROM 
    [TABLE2]
```